# CasperJS with Slimerjs - Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99"

Tags: linux, centos, casperjs, xvfb, slimerjs

I am trying to running **Casperjs with Slimerjs**

- I Installed SlimerJS 0.10.2
- I have installed Mozilla Firefox 45.5.1 (tried with 50 too)
- I have installed CasperJS 1.1.3
- I have installed xvfb 1.17.4

Running on Centos 6.8

When tried to run a casperjs+slimerjs from php I get:

```
Gecko error: it seems /usr/bin/firefox is not compatible with SlimerJS.
See Gecko version compatibility. If version is correct, launch slimerjs
with --debug=true to see Firefox error message
```

When I try to run a script from console with debug=true like:
`/usr/local/bin/casperjs /tmp/casperjs-5cn484 --debug=true --engine=slimerjs`
(I tried with `xvfb-run` too)

I get this error:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
process 5588: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to open "/var/lib/dbus/machine-id": No such file or directory
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Redirecting call to abort() to mozalloc_abort

/usr/lib/node_modules/slimerjs/src/slimerjs: line 167:  5588 Segmentation fault      "$SLIMERJSLAUNCHER" -app "$SLIMERDIR/application.ini" $PROFILE -no-remote "$@"
```

if i run `slimerjs --debug=true`, I get:

`Error: cannot open display: :1.1
Gecko error: it seems /usr/bin/firefox is not compatible with SlimerJS.
See Gecko version compatibility. If version is correct, launch slimerjs
with --debug=true to see Firefox error message`

I already tried a lot of solution, like:

- tried: `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension RANDR &` and `export DISPLAY=:1` (with :99 too)
- tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`
- upgrade downgrade firefox version
- check if there was fonts, there is one, so no problem

I don't know what I am trying anymore, some suggestions? : )

Comment: `pkill [X,x]vfb; pkill nw; Xvfb :1 -screen 1 1440x900x24 >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: `export DISPLAY=:1.1`

Comment: it seems that this would have fixed it, but it doesn't. Other suggestions?
Edited with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I get it running installing dbus package and with the comand:

```
dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
```

The `Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99"` isn't a big issue...

from:
[http://www.torkwrench.com/2011/12/16/d-bus-library-appears-to-be-incorrectly-set-up-failed-to-read-machine-uuid-failed-to-open-varlibdbusmachine-id/](http://dbus-uuidgen%20%3E%20/var/lib/dbus/machine-id)

Answer (score -1):

Did you see [this issue](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues/359)? Apparently you should:

> Change the max version in src/application.ini
>   MaxVersion=45.*

I'm not sure about the xrandr error but it seems unrelated. Could be a result of experimentation or a red herring.

There's also a DBUS error that could be causing the subsequent segmentation fault.

I suggest you try to check it step by step:

- see that firefox is working

  - [X forwarding](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html) might help here, it would bring up the remote firefox window locally
- make sure that firefox is working headless

  - you could generate [an xvfb screenshot](http://www.leonardteo.com/2011/07/taking-server-side-screenshots-of-websites/)
- check with slimerjs
- check with your PHP wrapper script

Comment: I have already checked the version issue, is it very old, now the default value is already 50.*